# Xcode 6 warning: Argument unused during compilation and I get several .d files in message

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I get this Xcode 6 warning: "Argument unused during compilation", and I get several .d files in the Issue Navigator.

Some background of how the project is organized will probably point to where my issue lies. I have two targets, and they have slightly different settings. One is for the automated build, and the other is the development one. The Develop does not have this warnings. The automated build one was duplicated from the Develop one. Of course, Xcode generated different plist files, so I had to make sure they both used the same to not have to maintain duplicate settings. I also had to change the Product Name, since the auto build one would otherwise export with it's funny name (it has _CI appended to the name of the App). That would cause some issue.

Also, I'm using Cocoa Pods, in case this might have to do with the issue?

I'm using both Swift and Objective C, and I have unit tests set up.

Here's what the warning looks like, exactly:

```
Argument unused during compilation: '-MF /Users/user.name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_iOS-akqwlfytlhwajobqkbaqgojblmet/Build/Intermediates/App_iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App_iOS_CI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuModel.d'
```

Hope this helps pinpoint the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ever figure this one out?